# VB.net Delete a file which keeps getting replaced

Tags: vb.net, .net

I have written a VB.net executable that deletes a file then transfers a different one in it's place.  An extract of the code is shown below.  The problem is it fails every time due to the program that uses the file recreates it immediately after deletion.

How can I delete the file and prevent it being replaced?  I cannot change anything about the program that's recreating it.

```
    If IO.File.Exists(AMPDir & "AMP_DIR.DAT") = False Then
        MsgBox("The following file is missing..." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "      " & "AMP_DIR.DAT", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error...")
        Me.Close()
        End
    ElseIf IO.File.Exists(AMPDir & "AMP_DIR.DAT") = True And IO.File.Exists(LOGDir & "LOGIC.INF") = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(AMPDir & "AMP_DIR.DAT")
        System.IO.File.Copy(Path.GetDirectoryName(ConfigFile) & "\" & "AMP_DIR.DAT.IND", AMPDir & "AMP_DIR.DAT")
        System.IO.File.SetAttributes(AMPDir & "AMP_DIR.DAT", FileAttributes.Normal)
    End If
```

Comment: Don't delete it first, just use the overload of [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) that lets you replace the existing file.

Comment: Nope, tried this first but it didn't work.

Comment: instead of deleting the original file, rename it.  Instead of creating a new file to replace it, create a new file with another name and then rename it to replace the original.  In other words two renames in immediate succession.  ??